# SMS send time optimization , what type of censoring and border to use?

Tags: survival

My project is to develop a model that will perform SMS ad-campgain send time optimization. I have got data about SMS-send time and SMS open time, gender, and a lot of binary features that provide information about user speciality. My model has to choose the best send time of sms for certain user.

Survival analysis is so-called "time-to-event analysis", that's why I decided to use this technique, but there is one question. There are a lot of users that did not open SMS, that's why value in "open time" column is NaN.

Moreover, some users have just 1 message, others more than one, so for different users the value of sent sms is different (up to 10).

So, my question is: what type of censoring and to what border I have to use for this type of "unrespond" users? Or, maybe survival analysis is not the best approach to use in that task ?

Comment: Notice that the users can simply turn off sending return receipts, so if you don't have "open time" it could be either that the user ignored the SMS or that they just didn't confirm receiving it. Moreover, this doesn't sound like a great criteria to optimize. For example, I can imagine that your users may be more likely to open SMS when commuting to work vs when at work. On another hand, when commuting to work they may be also less likely to pay attention to the message since they are in hurry or distracted.

Comment: @Tim , Thank you for your answer! But, let's suppose that not having open time means that user did not open it and I decided to use the survival analysis. Speaking about the censoring, what can I use? I tried to use right censoring till current date but that did not make sense((